# What are the parameters of host_subplot in matplotlib's mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand how [this Matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_parasite_axes2.html) plot is made so I can derive from it for my own program:

[image]

The very first line of code is

```
host = host_subplot(111, axes_class=AA.Axes)
```

and I am trying to figure out what those parameters are to avoid "magic source code" in the future.  A call to `pydoc` doesn't say much:

```
$ pydoc2.7 mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.host_subplot
Help on function host_subplot in mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1:
mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.host_subplot = host_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
```

The library [source code](https://fossies.org/dox/matplotlib-1.4.3/_2parasite__axes_8py_source.html#l00496) isn't very illuminating:

> def host_subplot(*args, **kwargs)

Moreover, in my search I've found that lots of these examples have that magical *111* parameter and I have no idea what it does.

Can anybody help me figure out:

1. what the arguments of `host_subplot()` are
2. how to go about finding this out for myself when `pydoc` and online documentation fail?

Comment: [This](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html) is a simpler example that does the same thing without `host_subplot`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you can find more info on `host_subplot` (I presume you have seen [this page](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/overview.html#parasiteaxes)?), but the `111` argument must get passed onto `subplot` at some point, and is shorthand for saying `1 row`, `1 column`, `plot number 1`.

[From the docs:](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)

> Typical call signature:
>
> `subplot(nrows, ncols, plot_number)`
>
> Where `nrows` and `ncols` are used to notionally split the figure into `nrows * ncols` sub-axes, and plot_number is used to identify the particular subplot that this function is to create within the notional grid. plot_number starts at 1, increments across rows first and has a maximum of `nrows * ncols`.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to tell from the `host_subplot()` definition that it derives from `subplot()`?

Comment: actually, looking at it, I think it uses `add_subplot` (which is the `Axes` method similar to `subplot`). If you look [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid1/parasite_axes.py#L472) you'll see that it calls `fig.add_subplot(ax)`